# JSON handling in Django

Tags: django, json

My data is in JSON-format;

```
{"user": "foo", 
"name": "foo", 
"email": "foo@bar.com",
"password":"password"}
```

I'm requesting a resource by curl

```
curl -X POST address/resource --data-urlencode @file
```

Problem is that I cannot deserialize the posted data at all. I have tried to use json.load / json.loads and deserialize but cannot access the attributes..

```
raw_data = json.load(request.POST)
raw_date = serializers.deserialize('json', raw_data )
```

At one point I managed to get DeserializedObject, but it didn't help.. How do I transform this JSON-data to python dictionary or some other format that I can access attributes?

Comment: "cannot access the attributes"?  What does that mean?  Why does your code show a two-step `json.load` AND a separate Django serializer?  Why do both?

Answer (score 0):

You want [`request.raw_post_data`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.raw_post_data).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this https://github.com/bradjasper/django-jsonfield

Answer (score 0):

```
import simplejson as json
_dict = json.loads("{'json':'string'})
```

or

```
import json
_dict = json.loads("{'json':'string'})
```

Notice the s on load`S`

Comment: Still getting HTTP 500 error. request.raw_post_data didn't work either.

Comment: curl -X POST  localhost:8000/api/users/ --data @user.json worked. For some reason I had --data-urlencode..